# Getting The ArrayList To Keep Each Account Balance And Number

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have completed my program an am stuck on getting each account balance

for example

If I enter the first savings account balance it will work fine however when I open another savings account the account balance of the first account will show the the last account balance I entered I will like to know what do I have to do correct this error any help will do thanks

```
package Object_1_Programs;
import  java.util.Date;
/**
 *
 * 
 */
public abstract class Account {

    //instance variables decleared
    private String c_name;
    private String acc_num;
    private double acc_balance;
   java.util.ArrayList transactions=new java.util.ArrayList();

   //default constructor 
    public Account(){


    }
    //Constructor

    public Account(String c_name,String acc_num,double  acc_balance){
        this.c_name=c_name;
        this.acc_num=acc_num;
        this.acc_balance=acc_balance;
    }

    //getters and setter method
    public String setName(){
        return this.c_name;
    }    

    public String getCname(){
        return this.c_name;
    }

    public String SetAccnum(String acc_number){
        return this.acc_num;
    }

    public String GetAccNum(){
        return this.acc_num;
    }

    public double setBalance(double balance){
        return this.acc_balance=balance;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return this.acc_balance;
    }
//end of getters an setters method

    //toString method decleared
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Customer Name"+this.c_name   +"Account Number:"+this.acc_num; 
    }

    //beginning of withdrawal method
    public void  withdraw(double total){
        if(acc_balance<total){
            System.out.print("Not enough funds sorry your current balance is "+acc_balance);
        }
        else{
        this.acc_balance -= total;
        System.out.print("\n"+"Your Balance is"+ this.acc_balance);}

        Transaction t1 = new Transaction(new Date(), 'W', this.acc_balance, "Withdrawal Made");
        transactions.add(t1);

    }
    //end of withdrawal method


    //beginning of deposit method
   public void deposit(double total){
       this.acc_balance += total;
       System.out.printf("\n"+total+"Your Balance is"+ this.acc_balance);
        Transaction t1 = new Transaction(new Date(), 'D', this.acc_balance, "Deposit Made");
        transactions.add(t1);


   }
   //end of deposit method


}

This is the transaction class

package Object_1_Programs;

//Date decleared
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @
 */
public class Transaction {

    //instance variables decleared
    private Date date;
    private char type;
    private double amount;
    private double acc_balance;
    private String description;

    //Constructor
    public Transaction(Date date, char type, double acc_balance, String description) {
        this.acc_balance = acc_balance;
        this.date = new Date();
        this.type = type;

        this.description = description;
    }

//getters and setters method decleared
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public Date setDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public char getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public char setType() {
        return type;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return acc_balance;
    }

    public double setBalance() {
        return acc_balance;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public double setAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String setDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    //Tostring method 
    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return "\n"+new Date()      + "Type : " + type     +      "Account Balance " + acc_balance + "Description " + description;
    }
}


This is the Saving Account Class

import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @
 */
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
// instance variables decleared
    private double int_rate;

    //default constrictor
    public SavingsAccount(){
      int_rate=0;  
    }
//main construtor
    public SavingsAccount(String c_name, String acc_num, double acc_balance, double int_rate) {
        super(c_name,acc_num, acc_balance);
        this.int_rate = int_rate;
    }
//getters and setters method decleared
    public double setRate(double rate) {
        return int_rate=rate/100;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return int_rate;
    }


//payInterest method decleared
    public void payInterest() {
        double acc_amount=getBalance();
        double balance=0;
        balance = (acc_amount + (acc_amount *getRate()));
        setBalance(balance);

        System.out.printf("Account Balance With Interest is %.2f", setBalance(balance));
        Transaction t1 = new Transaction(new Date(),    'I'     ,        setBalance(balance), "Interest Paid");
        transactions.add(t1);

    }
//Withdrawal method override
    @Override
    public void withdraw(double total) {
        double acc_amount = getBalance();
        double balance = 0;

        if (acc_amount < total) {
            System.out.printf("Not enough funds your main account balance is :$%.2f", acc_amount);
        } else {

                    balance=acc_amount -= total;
                   setBalance(balance);
            System.out.printf("Your withdrawal of :$" + total + " was successful your new  account balance is :$%.2f",setBalance(balance));
        }
        Transaction t1 = new Transaction(new Date()     ,    'W'     ,       setBalance(balance), "Withdrawal Made");
        transactions.add(t1);


    }
//Deposit method override
    @Override
    public void deposit(double total) {
        double balance;
        double acc_amount = getBalance();
        balance= acc_amount+=total;
        setBalance(balance);
        System.out.printf("Your deposit of :$" + total + " was successful your new account balance is :$%.2f",setBalance(balance));
        Transaction t1 = new Transaction(new Date()     ,     'D'    , setBalance(balance),  "Deposit Made");
        transactions.add(t1);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.toString() + "Interest Rate: " + int_rate;
    }


}


This is the Chequing Class

package Object_1_Programs;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class ChequingAccount extends Account {
// instance variable decleared
    private double over_draft;
// default constructor
    public ChequingAccount() {
        this.over_draft = 500;
    }
    //end of default constructor


//Main Constructor begins
    public ChequingAccount(String c_name, String acc_num, double acc_balance) {
        super(c_name, acc_num, acc_balance);

    }
    //End of Main Method


// Getters and Setters method
    public double setOverDraft() {
        return over_draft = 500;

    }


//To string override
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.toString() + "Over Draft Limit :" + over_draft;
    }

    //Withdrawal method override
    @Override
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        double acc_amount = getBalance();
        double balance = 0;
        if (amount >balance &&  amount>  over_draft) {
            System.out.println("Sorry I cannot give you that amount choose a lower amount or tell d girl yuh cah remember yuh pin");
        } 
        else {
              balance= acc_amount-= amount;
              setBalance(balance);

        }
        System.out.printf(amount+ "Your new balance is %.2f", setBalance(balance));
        Transaction t1 = new Transaction(new Date()     , 'W',       setBalance(balance), "Withdrawal Made:");
        transactions.add(t1);

    }

    //Deposit Method override
    @Override
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        double acc_amount = getBalance();
        double balance=0;
        balance=acc_amount += amount;
        setBalance(balance);
        System.out.printf("Your deposit of :$" + amount + " was successful your new account balance is :$%.2f",setBalance(balance));
        Transaction t1 = new Transaction(new Date()     , 'D'    ,       setBalance(balance),      "Deposit Made:");
        transactions.add(t1);


    }


}


This is my test program

public class Account_Records_Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        ArrayList Savings =new ArrayList();
        ArrayList Chequing=new ArrayList();



        String name;
        char type;
        char selection;
        double balance;
        double rate;
        String acc_num;       
        double total;


        SavingsAccount s1 = new SavingsAccount();
        ChequingAccount c1 = new ChequingAccount();



        System.out.println("\n" + "Please select one of the following options");
        System.out.println("|  o-To Open Account       |");
        System.out.println("|  d-To Make A Deposit     |");
        System.out.println("|  w-To Make A Withdraw    |");
        System.out.println("|  i-To Pay Interest       |");
        System.out.println("|  t-To View Transactions  |");
        System.out.println("|  q-To Quit               |");
        type = input.next().trim().toUpperCase().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        while (type != 'q') {

            if (type == 'o') {
                System.out.print("Please select the type of account you will like to open s-Saving or c-Checking :");
                selection = input.next().trim().toUpperCase().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
                if (selection == 's') {
                    System.out.print("Please enter Account Holder Name");
                    name=input.next();

                    System.out.print("Please enter a Savings Account Number : ");
                    acc_num = input.next();
                    Savings.add(acc_num);

                    System.out.print("Please enter starting balance :$");
                    balance = input.nextDouble();
                    s1.setBalance(balance);



                    System.out.print("Please enter the courrent interest rate :");
                    rate = input.nextDouble();
                    s1.setRate(rate); 
                    Savings.add(acc_num);





                } else if (selection == 'c') {
                    System.out.print("Please enter a Chequing Account Number :");
                    acc_num = input.next();
                    Chequing.add(acc_num);
                    System.out.print("Please enter starting balance :$");
                    balance = input.nextDouble();
                    c1.setBalance(balance);
                }


            } else if (type == 'd') {
                System.out.print("Please enter the account number you wish to make a deposit to :");
                acc_num= input.next();

                if (Savings.contains(acc_num)) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter how much you will like to deposit to your Savings Account :$");
                    total = input.nextDouble();
                    s1.deposit(total);
                } else if (Chequing.contains(acc_num)) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter how much you will likt to deposit to your Chequing Account :$");
                    total = input.nextDouble();
                    c1.deposit(total);
                }

            } else if (type == 'w') {
                System.out.print("Please enter an account number  :");
                acc_num = input.next();
                if (Savings.contains(acc_num)) {
                    System.out.print("please enter the amount you wish to withdraw from your Saving Account");
                    total = input.nextDouble();
                    s1.withdraw(total);
                } else if (Chequing.contains(acc_num)) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter the amount you wish to withdraw from your Chequing Account");
                    total = input.nextDouble();
                    c1.withdraw(total);
                }
            } else if (type == 'i') {
                System.out.print("Please enter your account");
                acc_num = input.next();
                if (Savings.contains(acc_num)) {
                    s1.payInterest();
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Sorry This account isnt a Savings Account");
                }
            } else if (type == 't') {
                System.out.print("Please enter a account number");
                acc_num = input.next();
                if (Savings.contains(acc_num)) {
                    System.out.printf("\n" + "Transaction History for Account :%s", acc_num);
                    System.out.println(s1.transactions.toString());

                }
                else if(Chequing.contains(acc_num)) {
                    System.out.printf("\n" + "Transaction History for Account :%s", acc_num);
                    System.out.println(c1.transactions.toString());

                }

            }
            else if(type=='q'){
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("\n" + "Please select one of the following options");
            System.out.println("|  o-To Open Account       |");
            System.out.println("|  d-To Make A Deposit     |");
            System.out.println("|  w-To Make A Withdraw    |");
            System.out.println("|  i-To Pay Interest       |");
            System.out.println("|  t-To View Transactions  |");
            System.out.println("|  q-To Quit               |");
            type = input.next().trim().toUpperCase().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }

    }
}


Any help will do thanks
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger and find out from that where the balance is coming from each time. If, having done that, you have not identified the problem, you should have narrowed it down to a small part of code that someone on SO might be able to help you with.

Comment: The Area Is in The Accounts Record test where am suppose to store the person account number with there balance

Comment: @user2301045 is it possible to run you code?

Comment: @Kitex yes it is but once i enter another account the balance from the new account is being displayed as the first whenever i enter the account number I just want to know what am missing to make it store both the number and balance for each account

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you only created one SavingsAccount object (s1). Everytime you "open an account" you are overwriting the one SavingsAccount that you made. I suggest making an ArrayList of SavingsAccounts like so: ArrayList accounts = new ArrayList();. Everytime you open an account, add the SavingsAccount object you create to "accounts."

It is also worth knowing that the "ArrayList name = new ArrayList();" syntax is deprecated. You should now put an identifier in the ArrayList declaration. The identifier, denoted as  specifies the type of object that the ArrayList holds.

Comment: @Micheal Hall how do i use it in an IF statement to which account is the user has?

Comment: I would use a for loop to iterate through each SavingsAccount object in the ArrayList. For each one say: if (account.getAccNum == input)...

Comment: I hope am not bothering you too much can i see an example again please

Comment: thanks @Micheal Hall will do it an tell you whats the outcome

Comment: @ Micheal Hall am now getting an error stating incomparable types if I put in as a String an still not getting the Savings Account Options

Answer (score 0):

There are also numerous other problems. For example, in `deposit()`:

```
balance=acc_amount += amount;
```

... should be:

```
balance = acc_amount + amount;
```

... and in:

```
System.out.printf("Your deposit of :$" + amount + " was successful your new account balance is :$%.2f",setBalance(balance));
```

... as well as in `withdraw()`, `setBalance()` should be `getBalance()`. The latter problem also occurs in `withdraw()`.

While `setBalance()` can be used in these contexts because it has been designed to return the balance as well as set the balance, there is a risk of it incorrectly setting the balance to something else while attempting to just print out what the balance is.

There is also much duplicated code that could be [refactored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) and it would be wise to think hard about a design that is made more complicated than is necessary because it intimately combines reporting balances with actioning transactions.

Comment: My code is running fine my only problem is that it isnt saving the account number with its balance it will use the next saving account balance in which i enter I will like to know how to save both please